# Problems with responsive drop down menu in wordpress

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I'm working with a genesis child theme called adaptation. It's a responsive theme, which is great. I added a fixed top bar (utility bar) from here http://www.carriedils.com/widget-area-above-header-genesis/ that I wanted to contain a responsive drop down menu, social media icons and a search field.

However, when I try to add a custom menu to that widget area, it no longer functions as a drop down. The sub menus show just slightly underneath. I've tried googling, but I can't figure out the answer. How to I get that menu in that widget area to function in the same way as a primary menu? Is it impossible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
This is the code I added to my functions.php:

```
    /** Register Utility Bar Widget Areas. */

    genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id' => 'utility-bar-left',
    'name' => __( 'Utility Bar Left', 'theme-prefix' ),
    'description' => __( 'This is the left utility bar above the header.', 'theme-prefix' ),
    ) );

    genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id' => 'utility-bar-right',
    'name' => __( 'Utility Bar Right', 'theme-prefix' ),
    'description' => __( 'This is the right utility bar above the header.', 'theme-prefix' ),
    ) );

add_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'utility_bar' );
/**
* Add utility bar above header.
*
* @author Carrie Dils
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2013, Carrie Dils
* @license GPL-2.0+
*/
function utility_bar() {

    echo '<div class="utility-bar"><div class="wrap">';

    genesis_widget_area( 'utility-bar-left', array(
        'before' => '<div class="utility-bar-left">',
        'after' => '</div>',
    ) );

    genesis_widget_area( 'utility-bar-right', array(
        'before' => '<div class="utility-bar-right">',
        'after' => '</div>',
    ) );

    echo '</div></div>';

}
```

The CSS that codes the primary and secondary navigation looks like this:

```
.genesis-nav-menu{
    clear: both;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a{
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a:hover,
.genesis-nav-menu .current-menu-item > a,
.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item > a:hover{
    color: #333;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    left: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:    opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:     opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:      opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    transition:         opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 99;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a{
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover{
    position: static;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu{
    left: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Site Header Navigation
--------------------------------------------- */

.site-header .sub-menu {
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}

.site-header .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    margin-top: -56px;
}

.site-header .genesis-nav-menu li li {
    margin-left: 0;
}

/* Primary Navigation
--------------------------------------------- */

.nav-primary {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
} 

.nav-primary:before {
    border-top: 3px double #eee;
    height: 3px;
    width: 84%;
    margin: -20px auto 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

/* Responsive Navigation
--------------------------------------------- */

.responsive-menu-icon,
.responsive-menu .menu-item-has-children {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.responsive-menu .menu-item,
.responsive-menu-icon {
    display: block;
}

.responsive-menu,
.responsive-menu > .menu-item > .sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

.responsive-menu-icon {
    text-align: center;
}

.responsive-menu-icon::before {
    color: #000;
    content: "\f333";
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal 20px/1 'dashicons';
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.responsive-menu > .menu-item-has-children:before {
    content: "\f347";
    float: right;
    font: normal 16px/1 'dashicons';
    height: 16px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.responsive-menu .menu-open.menu-item-has-children:before {
    content: "\f343";
}

.responsive-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to help you without any code to see.

Comment: I've added some code. What other code would you like to see?